# program keeps saying 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python

I am supposed to write a program that asks a user their name and the year of their birth, and them outputs their name and their age in a properly formatted sentence.

It was supposed to turn out like e.g `hello,xoxo, you are 15 years old`, but it is saying:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                            
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>                                                                                         
    print("Hello,"),Name,"you are"(int(2019)-int(birth),"years old")                                                          
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: We can't help without seeing q little more your code, so please [edit] your question and add it.

Comment: Consult your training materials on the `print` command.  You haven't mastered the command syntax.

Comment: I *think* what you want is `print("Hello", Name, "you are", 2019-birth, "years old")`

Comment: The error is due to your illegal syntax `"you are"(...)`.  The parentheses after a string constant are illegal.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error is that you are "calling" a string (text) object. This means that you are using the syntax for invoking a function, but with a string: i.e. typing parenthesis after it, as in the `"your are"(int(2019)-int(birth),"years old")` part. This is correct if you are calling a function, e.g. 'print **()** ', but not if the preceding item is a string.

The correct version of this line would be:

```py
print("Hello,", Name, "you are", 2019 - int(birth), "years old")
```

(Note that I have replaced `int(2019)` with `2019`, as this is redundant - python can work out that 2019 is an integer without explicitly converting it to one. I also removed the close-parenthesis after `print("Hello,"` to ensure that the whole line gets printed, and added some whitespace to enhance readability.)